# Bootstrap datepicker - Date value lost after autoclose

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker, modal-dialog

Im trying to use **datepicker inside a bootstrap modal** and i've found that some people had problems with this and they solved it with `z-index` attribute. **In my case, the calendar shows up without any problems** when I click on the input field, but when I chose the date nothing happens.

If I set `autoclose: false` I can see that datepicker sets the date value inside the input, but if I click outside the input, the value disappears.

**Inputs**

```
<input class="form-control datepicker" type="text" name="buscar-desde" autocomplete="off">
<input class="form-control datepicker" type="text" name="buscar-hasta" autocomplete="off">
```

**JS**

```
$('#modal-buscar-finalizadas').on('shown.bs.modal', function() {
            $('.datepicker').datepicker({
                format: "dd/mm/yyyy",
                language: "es",
                autoclose: true,
                todayHighlight: true,

            });
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved using stopPropagation() method on datepicker hide event, you may close this.

```
$('.datepicker').datepicker().on('hide', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        event.stopPropagation();
    });
```

https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/issues/1032